# Why are "Null Like X" and "Not (Null Like X)" equal?

Tags: sql, null, sql-like

I understand why these 2 statements are false

```
NULL LIKE 'X'
NULL NOT LIKE 'X'
```

However, what I don't understand is why these are :

```
NOT (NULL LIKE 'X')
NOT (NULL NOT LIKE 'X')
```

For example, these two statements should, I think, return different values :

```
SELECT CASE WHEN NOT (NULL LIKE 'X') THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END
SELECT CASE WHEN     (NULL LIKE 'X') THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SQL uses a [three-valued logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29#Three-valued_logic_.283VL.29). You say that these are all false:

```
NULL LIKE 'X'
NULL NOT LIKE 'X'
NOT (NULL LIKE 'X')
NOT (NULL NOT LIKE 'X')
```

but that's actually not true. They're all null, which is *neither* true *nor* false.

A `WHEN` or `WHERE` clause rejects non-true values, which means null values as well as false ones, so it may seem like null is the same as false, but as you've noticed, it's not. :-)

Comment: Thanks, I understood easily with your post. I thought that `NULL LIKE [Whatever]` was false, not null. Didn't thought that `LIKE` could return `NULL`

Comment: @Tipx: You're welcome! Yeah, the three-valued logic is one of the more confusing, and controversial, aspects of SQL.

Answer (score 2):

`NULL` is always `NULL` you cannot compare it to something like that. It cannot be true or false which is what you are looking for as an answer.

It is just like you cannot compare, this will always return zero rows because `NULL` is an unknown value.

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable 
WHERE yourCol = NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

NULL is always undefined.

So the value of

```
not (NULL like X) is undefined
```

and  also

```
not (NULL not like X) is undefined
```

The best approximation of Undefined is NULL so both statements evaluate to NULL (NOT, you understand, equal NULL, we don't know what they equal)